# Trying to make a login session hook in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this in hook.php:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'Account',
    'function' => 'check_user_login',
    'filename' => 'authenticate.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks/authenticate',
    'params'   => array()
    );
```

and this in hooks folder authenticate.php:

```
<?php
class Account
{
    function check_user_login()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('pag/index');    
        }else{
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I want to make the login session available for all the models/controlers, but something is not right, I also did set the $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE; thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this (`hooks.php`)

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                               'class'    => 'Authenticate',
                               'function' => 'check_user_login',
                               'filename' => 'Authenticate.php',
                               'filepath' => 'hooks',
                               'params'   => array()
                               );
```

Now hook file (`Authenticate.php`) in `hooks` folder

```
<?php
class Authenticate{
  protected $CI;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
  }
  public function check_user_login(){
      if(!$this->CI->session->is_logged_in){
          redirect('main/restricted');    
      }
  }
}
?>
```

You will need to reference the CI superobject with `$this->CI =& get_instance()` and then the finalized data will be available by calling `$this->CI..`

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

> If you are using CodeIgniter version 3 then may use
>   `$this->CI->session->is_logged_in` instead
>   `$this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in')`

Comment: It doesn't work, could be that something else is wrong, I will get from the controllers 404 not found.

Comment: Yes, I used with $this->CI->session->is_logged_in (I have CI 3)

Comment: @AnakinVader have you replaced my code with yours? and noticed all changes?

Comment: Yep, but where shall I put the Authenticate.php script, controllers folder or config folder?

Comment: @AnakinVader in `hooks` folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130692/discussion-between-rejoanul-alam-and-anakin-vader).

Comment: Well, something has happened, now I will get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, when I will go to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

have you make the $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE; from the config.php file in config folder under application folder?

Comment: Can you rephrase that so it sounds more like an answer and less like a question?